# C# GPS location not drawing to screen?

Tags: android, gps, location, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to draw a label with the Lat and Lon of my phone location.
When I debug on the pc i'm returned with 0 , 0 . This is expected since i'm on a PC with no
GPS. The PC build does draw the label. When I run an android build of the same thing. The label is not drawing at all - i'm assuming because it isn't working properly.
My androidmanifest.xml is setup correctly with the correct permissions.

This is my GPS code - this is attached to a game object.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class GPS : MonoBehaviour {


float lat ;
float lon ;
float alt ;
float horz ;
float time ;
public GUIStyle myGuiStyle_CORDS;

IEnumerator Start (){
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)

    // Start service before querying location
    Input.location.Start ();
    // Wait until service initializes
    int maxWait = 20;

    while (Input.location.status
           == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }
    // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1) {
        print ("Timed out");

    }
    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed) {
        print ("Unable to determine device location");

    }
    // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
    else {
        iPhoneSettings.StartLocationServiceUpdates();


        print ("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " +
               Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " +
               Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " +
               Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " +
               Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
    }


    // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
    Input.location.Stop ();
}

void  OnGUI (){
    if (Globals.DisplayMode == "GPSST") {
        GUI.depth = 0;
        lon = Input.location.lastData.longitude;
        lat = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
        GUI.Label (new Rect (Globals.displayOffsetX + 5, 110, 100, 50), "" + Input.location.lastData.longitude, myGuiStyle_CORDS);
        GUI.Label (new Rect (Globals.displayOffsetX + 5, 130, 100, 50), "" + Input.location.lastData.latitude, myGuiStyle_CORDS);


    }
}


}
```

Comment: Most likely you are drawing outside the camera for your phone. Have you tried looking at what value Globals.displayOffsetX holds? Why not use Screen.Width instead?

Comment: Globals.displayOffsetX is at 40,40. I have other things in that position that appear fine on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons

1) You are stopping the location service at the last line of Start(). Did you forget return-commands in the if-statements? Such as:

```
if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    return;

if (maxWait < 1) {
    print ("Timed out");
    return;
}
```

2) Your first if-statement is related to Input.location.Start()

```
if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
    Input.location.Start()
```

maybe that is not intended?

3) Your if-statement in the OnGUI() returns false

Comment: Adding the return statments gave me -
Assets/MainMenu/Scripts/GPS.cs(17,25): error CS0126: An object of a type convertible to `bool' is required for the return statement.

Comment: That's because you are using IEnumerator which is used for coroutines. I presume you are using coroutines otherwise you don't need that. You can exit coroutine with `yield break;` instead of `return`

Answer (score 0):

first, activate your location services at Start() method

```
string message = "";
int maxwait = 20; //my top waiting time for location start
Input.location.Start(1,1);
While(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
{
     new WaitForSeconds(1f);
     maxWait--;
}
if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
   message = "Unable to run location";
else
{
   if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running)
      message = "location Running";
   else
      message = Input.location.status.ToString();
}
```

this is what i used, also activated compass but I think you are not using
if you are, then just add Input.compass.enabled = true; where you know service is Running

good luck and happy coding;